# Compound listener in a renderer

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlist, listcellrenderer

I have own ListCellRenderer for JList. The elements of the JList are the JPanel's. When i click on the list i have to focus on it (for example: list.getSelectedIndex()). But I need to also focus on the JPanel and the elements that are in the JPanel.

Here is my code:

```
ListCellRenderer<ClipboardObjectView> listCellRenderer = new ListCellRenderer<ClipboardObjectView>() {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                JList<? extends ClipboardObjectView> list,
                ClipboardObjectView value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                boolean cellHasFocus) {
            return value;
        }
    };
```

ClipboardObjectView is my JPanel. I did a mouseListener for ClipboardObjectView but it does not work.

Comment: This is not how cell renders work, they are not "live" components.  Take a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: Thanks. In this article, however, I understand that it can be done despite the fact that the renderer is not a "live" compoment...?

Comment: Any listeners you attach to a "renderer" in this way will never be called, because the component is never weired into the framework, instead a "snap shot" of it is taken and "painted" into the screen.  It would be like saying "Why can't I click this print out of my window?"

Comment: Why are you using a JList with a panel as a renderer? If you have multiple values to render for each row you should probably be using a JTable. You can select individual cells of a table.

Comment: Thanks Mad. Maybe JTable with listener on every cell is a better idea. I will use the table.